# LINQ expression returns nothing but why

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to create a simple LINQ query like so

```
 tj.lifetime == (int)timebase.unlimited
 && jg.permanent == "Y"
 && cc.contact == contactId 
 && cc.authorise != "Y"
```

Now in my database one CC that is the contact correct ID and has authorise as N
and i have another with a differnet ID and authorise as Y, but when I run this query i get no results at all. Any reason why?

Comment: You can easily see the SQL that LINQ2SQL is producing by placing a breakpoint in the code or implementing a logger against your data context. This should be the *very* first thing you should be doing to debug problems like this - find out the exact SQL that is being produced and run it.

Comment: Are all the other conditions also met for the item you expect to be returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're doing `AND` operations on multiple conditions, and you'll get records that match ALL of these conditions. None of your records that you mention matches all of these conditions.

Comment: is there a better way to write this query?

Comment: @Canvas it depends on what you want the query to return. You have not done very well explaining the expected behavior.

Comment: I do apologize, but i have changed some of my && to || and it seems to work, i'm very new to LINQ so everything is a little overwhelming :), but thank you for your answer